# Oracle Regexp_like using AND clause

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

I'm looking to find all occurrences of "`Dr. Jones`" in a name field using regexp_like. I can do the OR (all names with DR or JONES in it) but I need both names to be present in the field.

Is there a simple way to do this with regexp_like without using multiple statements?

I'm looking for a shortcut way. The answer below gives it in an easy situation.
I know I can have:

```
where regexp_like(color_code,'red|blue|green','i');
```

and it will give me any record of color_code with either of those three names in it.
What I'm looking for is something like:

```
where regexp_like(color_code,'red&blue&green','i');
```

that would only select records with ALL THREE colors in the name but they can be in any order so: red blue green, green purple blue black red, yellow red orange green blue

would all make the list

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable
where regexp_like(txt,'(Dr.+Jones+)|(Jones.+Dr+)','i');
```

ok took away the need for period after dr and allowed the words to be switched

Comment: here is the fiddle for it I added your two examples  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b78944/2

Comment: no THIS works the way I want it
thanks for this!!!!
been racking my brain all day on how to figure this out

Comment: @user2744722 - you should have *edited your original answer* with a corrected solution instead of polluting the thread with a second response.  Please delete your original answer.  (You could also tidy up this one so it makes sense without the first response).

Comment: More importantly your `regex` includes false positives for any sentence with DR and JONES.  Check out my [version of your SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a32cd/1).  It always pays to include test data we expect not to appear in the result set.